# Skorokhod topology for function that are left continuous with right limits (i.e., lcrl or caglad)

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Could anyone please point me out in the direction of a book or a paper on Skorokhod topology on caglad functions? Or any other topology on that same space if this one fails. I expect that there is no magic hidden there, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

["Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05265-5) in Chapter VI. Skorokhod Topology and Convergence of Processes.

Also see ["Convergence of Probability Measures"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316962) by Patrick Billingsley.

They do Càdlàg, which is similar to the Càdlàd case by symmetry. I doubt anyone has done it instead just for Càdlàd, because it is too symmetric to the Càdlàg case, which is more commonly seen.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, however the book doesn't develop any theory for caglad functions.

Comment: @BenPovar yes it does page 348

Comment: The page starts with Remark 3.6. "We shall occasionally need to consider the space...". Is this the one you mean? Maybe we're looking at different editions? So caglad functions --- continuous from the left, limits on the right.

Comment: @BenPovar I mean starting at the bottom of the page. They do Càdlàg, which is similar to the Càdlàd case by symmetry. I doubt anyone has done it instead just for Càdlàd, because it is too symmetric to the Càdlàg case, which is more commonly seen.

Comment: I absolutely agree, however it would still be nice to have a reference specifically for caglad functions or at least a remark saying that no surprises arise there.